# 'dotnet test' doesn't discover any test

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit.net

I have a project where I can not run the tests using `dotnet test` while my colleague can. The error message I get is

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: No test is available in C:\projects\...\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Test.AnalyzeFirmwareRollout.dll. Make sure test project has a nuget reference of package "Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" and framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
```

The project does have a reference to Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk and the target framework is

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
```

in the csproj file. Any Ideas what could be going wrong here?

Comment: Since it's core and you're using xUnit, you need xUnit and the [xunit.runner.console](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit.runner.console) package.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a [mcve] - a complete project file, a simple test (just one no-op test is all you need) so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I forgot to add that I can also not run the tests from within visual studio. They arent discovered, even though I do have the xunit.runner.visualstudio package installed. I will get xunit.runner.console now and try again on the CLI.

Comment: @rickvdbosch this solved it. However, I still don't understand why it would work on my colleagues machine, since we are managing dependencies with paket, he also did not have xunit.runner.console in the project

Comment: Maybe he hase the runner locally because of some other project?

Comment: Maybe your colleague has Resharper installed on his Visual Studio

Comment: He does have resharper, however, I have it too. Interestingly, I have xunit.runner.visualstudio, but still couldn't see any tests in the test explorer. After adding xunit.runner.console and rebuilding, I can now also see and run them from test runner

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For running xUnit tests from command line, you will need the [xunit.runner.console](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit.runner.console) package.

Comment: For people who don't use Visual Studio (Rider in my case) and added xunit.runner.console yet can still not run the tests via 'dotnet test'. I noticed that I needed xunit.runner.visualstudio for 'dotnet test' to discover my tests. Which is rather counterintuitive, this blog post gave me the hint: https://andrewlock.net/running-tests-with-dotnet-xunit-using-cake/

Comment: I confirm, adding ```xunit.runner.visualstudio``` solves it.

Answer (score 1):

I found another reason. When I added a new test project (`*.csproj`), the main `*.sln` file wasn't re-generated, therefore `*.sln` didn't include a new test project. When I removed `*.sln` and created a new one, `dotnet test` starts invocating all tests.